# Background Image on Versions >= Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Problem with the Layout of my App on different Android-Versions.
I want to add a background image to my Fragment.
On Android 2.3.3 it works but on Version > 3 I can do what I want, it doesn't  appear.

My activity_main.xml for the Activity seems like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
>
    <TexView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity seems like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

I also tried to work with styles, but it didn't help:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

Is there any other possibilty to solve this problem?

Comment: can provide more details what actually happens? is background image is not being set or what?

Comment: I set the background image in activity_main.xml and set this to the contentView of my Activity. On my HTC Wildfire the background image appears, but on ma Samsung Nexus it doesn't. I also tried to work with styles, but this has no effect. I just want a background image.

Comment: try with  `android:src="@drawable/background`

Comment: sorry but this has no effect. It can't be so difficult...some more Information: In my Android Manifest i've got minSdkVersion=8 and targetSdkVersion=16.

Comment: I also tried know to set the background null in my style item...but this has no effect, too...

Comment: make sure background is not affected by any other part of the application or code,else it must be working

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem: I just set the targetSdkVersion to 10. But I don't know why it doesn't work with level 16...Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: that's great you solved this issue.